# How to provide Variable and CSV data for https Post Request in bzm-parallel controller?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I added Http sampler request against  bzm-parallel controller. And provided Header manager  parameter  and File upload parameter `${path}` but provided file upload configuration is not working.

Can someone please share how to provide CSV data and vaibles in Https request sampler added against bzm-parallel controller?

I get the error shown below although valid file is present at provided path in csv for variable `${path}`. Presently jmter bzm parallel controller is taking path where the .jmx is present and giving below error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\JMeter\jMeterTests\FLAMe\Test Execution\13Aug18\${path} (The system cannot find the file specified)
>   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

(**Is somewhere we need to provide directory location in jmeter explicitely?**)

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Controller doesn't change JMeter behaviour in terms of interpreting [functions and variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), the [sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which is placed under the Parallel Controller isn't different from the sampler which is not associated with the parallel controller.

Most probably your [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup is wrong therefore your `${path}` variable is not being set. You can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination:

[image: JMeter Parrallel Controller Variable]